# How to add CVV field to Magento checkout page

Tags: magento, field, addition, payment, checkout

I wanted to know how can we add additional fields like Card Holder Name and CVV to Payment Information form during Checkout process.
Please guide me in this, or provide reference where i can check how these fields can be added to the Credit Card form.

Thanks
T T

Answer (score 3):

Under System - Configuration - Payment Methods - Saved CC - Enabled = Yes and in the same section Request Card Security Code = Yes